# web sites that list the ticker symbols of high beta stocks?

Tags: stocks, investing, trading, stock-markets, beta

I want to invest in some high beta stocks.
The only list I've found is Yahoo finance, but it was only 5 stocks.

Comment: Reminder: questions seeking product, service recommendations or other off-site resources are off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FINVIZ offers about 15 free screeners which include over 7,500 stocks.

The one titled TECHNICAL has a sortable filter for Beta.